# python :'list' object is not callable while the problem doesnt come from list but split()

Tags: python, list

I want to split the string using different characters("."&" ",").I didn't know there is a module called re so I did it in a very stupid way:

```
text = ... HELLO WO,RLD, this
l2 = text.split(" ")
list(map(str.split(","), l2))
```

And it turned out:

```
'list' object is not callable`.
```

I am sure I didn't define a variable or function called list .It ran successfully after I rewrite `list(map(str.split(","),l2))` as `list(map(lambda x:x.split(","),l2))`.

Now I know I can use `re.split(" |,",text)`, but I still wanna know why the error is happened on list.

Comment: It turns out that `str.split(",")` - calling the method on the class instead of on an instance - returns the list `[',']`, which `map` tries to call. See the duplicate for the right way to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

`map` expects callable argument as first parameter str.split can be invoked

```
x = str.split
x()
```

while `str.split(",")` return a list, that's the cause of error.

You can use `lambda` to give `map` a callable function

```
list(map(lambda x: x.split(","), l2))
# [['...'], ['HELLO'], ['WO', 'RLD', ''], ['this']]
```